# C#: how to get all values for keys from JS Object?

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a C# application in web page. Web calls my apllication via JS:

```
var data = {key1:value1, key2:value2};
app["methodName"](data);
```

So, in my app:

```
public void methodName(object data)
{
   //need here something like this:
   foreach (var key in data)
   {
      var value = data[key];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Newtonsoft.JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/json) library lets you parse arbitrary JSON into a dynamic object like so:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

...

dynamic obj = JObject.Parse("{\"key1\":\"value1\", \"key2\":\"value2\"}");

Console.WriteLine(obj.key1);
Console.WriteLine(obj.key2);
```

---

The equivalent of the method you provided in your post would be similar to this:

```
public static void methodName(dynamic data)
{
    foreach (var keyValuePair in data)
    {
        var value = keyValuePair.Value;
        Console.WriteLine(keyValuePair.Name + ": " + keyValuePair.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```js
var data = {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'};
    
var arr = $.map(data,function(k,v){
    return k;
});
    
document.body.innerHTML = arr;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here, `arr` will have all the values.